# String replacement with jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, replace

With this html:

```
<blockquote class="stat">
  There are &rsquo;paper cups&lsquo; in there.
</blockquote>
```

I'm using this bit of jQuery:

```
function replaceEntity(element, entity, replacement) {
  $(element).each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(i, html) {
      return html.replace('‘', '<span class="rsquo">&rsquo;</span>').replace('’', '<span class="lsquo">&lsquo;</span>');
    });
  });
}
```

producing this:

```
<blockquote class="stat">
  There are <span class="rsquo"><span class="lsquo">‘</span></span>paper cups<span class="lsquo"><span class="rsquo">’</span></span> in there.
</blockquote>
```

but I want this:

```
<blockquote class="stat">
  There are <span class="rsquo">&rsquo;</span>paper cups<span class="lsquo">&lsquo;</span> in there.
</blockquote>
```

How can I

1. Get the search to scan for both entities without the nesting?
2. Stop jQuery replacing the html entities with UTF-8 equivalents?

---

**EDIT**

The nesting error was linked to another snippet in another devs doc. I'll delete this question eventually.

Comment: Once you insert entities with `html()` they are converted to the actual character, as that is what is supposed to happen to actually show the character instead of the entity. You could use `text()`, but that would expose the `span` tags as well -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/etkZy/) ?

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do here, string replacement as you're asking is plain JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah whether it is html entity or not is not super important, The issue of the nested spans was due to a loop in another devs work. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$('.stat').text('There are <span class="rsquo">&rsquo;</span>paper cups<span class="lsquo">&lsquo;</span> in there.').html();
```

but it's not interpreted like an Html element